# Excel VBA fiiting columns pricesly on point on DIN A4

Tags: excel, vba, width, cell

I have a little problem.
In one of my Excel sheets I have data in columns 2 to 88. Now I want to print these columns on a DIN A4 sheet. On this sheet there are 8 squares in one row. Now I need to fit 10 columns from my excel sheet in one square and have one spare column between this 10 columns and the next 10. So this means the 11th column should be half in the first square and the second square. This is why there is no data in column 1 on order to fit the first 10 on the square.

Now my problem is that Excel somehow can't set the right cm value for this columns to fit. It always sets it a little to big or small.
One column should be around 0.227 cm with 0,55 cm on each side as the edge. But if I now try this:

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
For i = 2 To 87
     ws.Columns(i).ColumnWidth = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.0227)
Next i
```

somehow 0.227 cm does not work for the function but 0.0227 does work for almost what I want. With this I get 0.24 but that is just slighlty off. 
So does anybody have a solution for this problem?

Comment: First, what's the default ruler measurement set to? `File Tab -> Options -> Advanced Tab -> Display Section -> Ruler Units`

Comment: Also: [MS Support: *The worksheet may be printed at a different size than you expect when you print a worksheet in Excel*](https://support.microsoft.com/help/288858/the-worksheet-may-be-printed-at-a-different-size-than-you-expect-when) and [How set column width/height in cm](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/137849-how-set-column-width-or-height-in-cms-or-inches-excel-2016)

Comment: Unit is default, Worksheet is printed DIN A4 with zoom at 100 %.
If it do it like in the tutorial it get's set from 0.227 to 0.21 which is not correct for what I want